# Hoested files are smaller in size, than their local ones

Tags: ftp, cpanel, host

I have uploaded my files using FileZilla. some of my files are smaller than their original local ones. Why such thing happens? Does active or passive ftp connection affect this?

Comment: are you transferring your files in `binary` or `ascii` mode?

Comment: it is set to auto-select

Comment: try so set it to binary and see if the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

This most likely due to your transfer method being set to ASCII, in which case the line endings might be translated from windows style (2 bytes) to Unix style (1 byte). Try setting the transfer mode to BINARY. Then the files should stay the same size. In theory the smaller files should still work/run fine.